# I want to use <i fas fa-home></i> but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I crafted the code as follows: `<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>`, yet the intended icon preceding 'Home' isn't displaying. What might be causing this issue, and how can it be rectified to ensure the icon appears correctly?

`<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>` home icon is what i'm expecting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is probably because you didn't include the CSS file. You should add this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">` and change the `href` to where your Font Awesome file are. This step is also mentioned in "[Get Started - fontawesome.com](https://fontawesome.com/v4/get-started/)"